# Telegram Inline Bot shows nothing inline with inlinekeyboard php

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I have problem with inline bot
my bot work without 'reply_markup' when I use 'reply_markup' nothing to show

```
function buildInlineKeyboard(array $options) {
   $replyMarkup = array(
            'inline_keyboard' => $options,
        );
        $encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup, true);
        return $encodedMarkup;
}

$keyboard = $tel->buildInlineKeyboard(array(
                    array(
                        $tel->buildInlineKeyboardButton('View Message', '', 'viewNews_')
                    )
                ));
                $item[] = array(
                    "type" => "article",
                    "id" => (string)++$i,
                    "title" => $plays['team1'] . " - " . $plays['team2'],
                    'description' => $title . ' - ' . $news['title'],
                    'input_message_content' => array(
                      'message_text' => $news['title'],
                      'parse_mode' => 'HTML'
                    ),
                    'reply_markup' => $keyboard
                );
```

when I comment 'reply_markup' bot work an show articles and when I use 'reply_markup' nothing to show in inline mode
I set webhook no error to show
$keyboard work with sendMessage

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the format of the `reply_markup` looks as following. There's probably something messed up with the `arrays`. You also need to `json_encode` the `reply_markup`.

```
array(1) {
  ["inline_keyboard"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["text"]=>
        string(12) "View Message"
        ["callback_data"]=>
        string(9) "viewNews_"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: correct array because I can use it in sendMessage API but not work on inline bot

Comment: Does `buildInlineKeyboard` `json_encode` the `reply_markup`?

Comment: yes this is the code $replyMarkup = array(
            'inline_keyboard' => $options,
        );
        $encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup, true);
        return $encodedMarkup;

Answer (score 0):

no the array is correct I update post and add buildInlineKeyboard function